# Phonegap single instance

Tags: android, cordova

Im using phonegap(3.5.0) and when I open my app on my galaxy S5, bring it to the backgound and start the application again by pushing the icon instead of pushing it by the menu of open apps, it shows the splashscreen again and restarts.

How can I continue instead of restarting?

I tried:

```
  <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
  <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleInstance" />
```

But none of them works. What is the reason?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "dk.mas.ap.geo"
    version   = "1.0.0">
<name>AP Geo</name>
<description>
    Module
</description>
<author href="http://akutplan.dk" email="support@akutplan.dk">
    Michael
</author>
<feature name="debug-server" required="false" />
<!--<preference name="permissions" value="none" />-->
<!--<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />-->
<!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
<preference name="phonegap-version"           value="3.5.0" />      <!-- all: current version of PhoneGap -->
<preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
<preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
<preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
<preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
<preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
<preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
<preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
<preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
<preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="7" />              <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
<preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
<!-- Plugins can also be added here. -->
<!--
    <gap:plugin name="Example" />
    A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins
-->
<gap:plugin name="org.transistorsoft.cordova.background-geolocation" version="0.2.0" />
<!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
<icon src="img/ap_icon.png" />

<!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"         gap:platform="blackberry" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" />



<!--
    Define access to external domains.

    <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
    <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.

    Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
-->
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
<!--
    <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
    <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
    <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
-->
```

Comment: I've never heard of it doing that. What version of Android do you have?

Comment: Dont use Phonegap, sorry : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001439/keeprunning-phonegap-cordova

Comment: Im running 4.4.2 on my android. Phonegap/cordova should support singletask/singleinstance from 3.5.0

Comment: Cocorico - org.transistorsoft.cordova.background-geolocation it works fine and stays in the background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest/application">
    <activity android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
</gap:config-file>
```

but in your config's widget setting, it should be like this (add the android namespace definition):

```
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        id        = "com.wildabeast.app"
        version   = "1.0.0">
....
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have "deviceready" event as well. But look at "pause" event:
*The pause event fires when the native platform puts the application into the background, typically when the user switches to a different application.*

Try this one:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html

Comment: What do you suppose to do in the onPause event to keep the instance?